# How to find multiple key/value pair combination array in unother multiple key/value array in php

Tags: php

I have a array list (for this example I'm using Googles colors). I'm wanting to be able to search for multiple key/value pairs if found the pair of array then return true otherwise return false.

**Input Like below color and lenscolor pair :** 
***This value are dynamic comes from dynamic dropdown***
    Array
    (
        [Color] => Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green
        [LensColor] => Green
    )

**In this array search above color and lenscolor pair** 
***This value are dynamic comes from xml file(converted in array)***
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Color] => Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown
                [LensColor] => Brown
            )

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke
            [LensColor] => Smoke
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green
            [LensColor] => Green
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke
            [LensColor] => Green
        )
    [4] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown
            [LensColor] => Green
        )
    [5] => Array
        (
            [Color] => Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown
            [LensColor] => Smoke
        )

)
```

Comment: Both array (what i search and which in i search)
are dynamic then how i use in if condition

Answer (score 0):

This is idea of would be, very simple:

```
    $arr =Array(Array
    (
        "Color" => "Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke",
        "LensColor" => "Smoke"
    ),

    Array(
        "Color" => "Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green",
        "LensColor" => "Green"
    ),
    Array(
        "Color" => "Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke",
        "LensColor" => "Green"
    ),
    Array(
        "Color" => "Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown",
        "LensColor" => "Green"
    ),
    Array(
        "Color" => "Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown",
        "LensColor" => "Smoke"
    )
            );
$founded = false;
$Color ="Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green";
$LensColor="Green";
echo $Color;
for ($i=0; $i<count($arr);$i++){

if($arr[$i]['Color']==$Color &&  $arr[$i]['LensColor']==$LensColor){
$founded=true;
break;
}
}
echo var_dump($founded);
```

It can make more sofisticated.

Comment: This Value are dynamic.......... $Color & $LensColor
then how i add in for loop if condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is the direct implementation of an iterative search strategy:

```
<?php
$haystack = [
    [
        'Color' => 'Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke',
        'LensColor' => 'Smoke'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green',
        'LensColor' => 'Green'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke',
        'LensColor' => 'Green'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown',
        'LensColor' => 'Green'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown',
        'LensColor' => 'Smoke'
    ]
];
$needle = [
    'Color' => 'Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green',
    'LensColor' => 'Green'
];
$result = false;
array_walk(
    $haystack, 
    function ($entry) use ($needle, &$result) {
        if (   ($entry['Color'] === $needle['Color'])
            && ($entry['LensColor'] == $needle['LensColor']) ) {
            $result = true;
        }
    }
);
var_dump($result);
```

The output obviously is:

```
bool(true)
```

---

An alternative strategy is to filter the haystack:

```
<?php
$haystack = [
    [
        'Color' => 'Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke',
        'LensColor' => 'Smoke'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green',
        'LensColor' => 'Green'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke',
        'LensColor' => 'Green'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown',
        'LensColor' => 'Green'
    ],
    [
        'Color' => 'Feathered Carmel,matte Gunmetal & Brown',
        'LensColor' => 'Smoke'
    ]
];
$needle = [
    'Color' => 'Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green',
    'LensColor' => 'Green'
];
$result = array_filter(
    $haystack,
    function ($entry) use ($needle) {
        return (   ($entry['Color'] === $needle['Color'])
                && ($entry['LensColor'] == $needle['LensColor']));
    }
);
var_dump($result);
```

The output of that certainly is:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Color"]=>
    string(33) "Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green"
    ["LensColor"]=>
    string(5) "Green"
  }
}
```

---

UPDATE: 
In the comments to the question you now ask a more complex question stating that both the needles and the haystacks array elements are of dynamic nature, so that a matching based on fixed array entries is not possible. Though the exact matching criteria has not been defined I can give a short hint on what modifications probably point into the right direction:

The matching criteria has to be changed, easiest is to test the identity of the two arrays. So you use something like the following as comparison callback inside the iteration loop instead of above code:

```
function ($entry) use ($needle) {
    return $entry === $needle;
}
```

That will only accept a match if the two arrays are identical in both their set of keys and the contained values.

Comment: This Value are dynamic $needle = Array ( [Color] => Tokyo Tortoise,matte Gold & Green [LensColor] => Green )

Comment: @SumitGupta Sure, it obviously is. The examples above only assume some arbitrary values according to your question. You certainly can fill `$needle` however you like.

Comment: if suppose 
$needle = Array ( [Color] => Matte Black,matte Black & Smoke [LensColor] => Smoke)

then i go for the change the function condition values?

Comment: @SumitGupta What do you mean by "then i go for the change the function condition values"? The code searches for whatever value `$needle` contains without you having to modify anything. That is the whole point of coding a search strategy.

Comment: The both array are dynamic (in which i search and what i search)
Suppose i have

Search array like  `$needle = Array
(
    [Size] => XL
    [Lenswidth] => 3mM
)`  The key and value both are dynamic

Comment: @SumitGupta That is not what you asked in the question itself. Certainly what you now ask is possible, but you will have to describe what you actually consider a match and what not. So for example: a match means that _all_ elements of the needle have to be present in an element of the haystack. Or that the elements of the needle need to _exactly_ match the elements of the matching element in the haystack, so that the later does not have any additional entries. Or that a haystack element is considered to match if _any_ if its elements matches one present in the needle.

Comment: can you have solution for that. 
`$needle = Array ( [Size] => XL [Lenswidth] => 3mM )`

Comment: Sure, but not if you do not answer the question I asked in the comment above. You need to define when exactly elements are considered to match.

Comment: @SumitGupta Ok, since you did not answer to my question all I can do is _guess_ what matching criteria you have in mind. I added an UPDATE to the answer pointing out the modification of the matching criteria you have to apply.

Comment: Yes, I was same type answer i want same time solution.